# Show that $m=\frac{a^{2p}-1}{a^2-1}$ is composite

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Restrictions are: $a>1$ and $p$ is an odd prime that does not divide $a(a^2-1)$. Through factorizing we can write $$m=\frac{(a^p+1)(a^p-1)}{(a+1)(a-1)}=\Bigl(\frac{a^p+1}{a+1}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}\Bigr).$$

Presumably you can then show that each of these terms is an integer, and therefore $m$ is composite. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also write $(a^2)^p - 1 = (a^2 -1)(a^{p-1} + a^{p-2} + \cdots + 1)$ if that helps.

Comment: http://studylib.net/doc/10375584/cipolla-pseudoprimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^p-1 = (a-1)(a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}+...+a^1+1)$ So the first term you have written is an integer. And we know that for odd numbers of p:

$a^p+1=(a+1)(a^{p-1}-a^{p-2}+a^{p-3}-...+1)$

So the second term you have written is also an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$ is odd, plug $-1$ in for $a$ to see that $(-1)^p+1=0$.  Therefore $x+1$ is a factor of $x^p+1$, which shows $(a^p+1)/(a+1)$ is an integer.  Repeat with $a=1$ for the second factor.